# Object reshaped by morph target retains shading from its original shape

Tags: animation, blender, unreal, normals, shading

I created an asset with a morph target in Blender. I captured GIFs of manipulating morph targets from 0 to 1 in both applications. When the morph target is 0, the mesh is serrated. It is correct to cast shading through the irregularities. When the morph target is 1, the serrated form changes to a flat surface. There should be no shading at this time. Blender doesn’t have shading, but Unreal Engine flattens them with shading. Why do morph targets in Unreal Engine have wrong shading?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Some hypotheses: could be that the normals are not being updated by the morph in Unreal, or the shader being used is not configured correctly to use those altered normals. Could be that the shading information got baked into a light map, or even a normal map, instead of being recomputed in realtime. Unfortunately I don't know enough of the guts of rendering and animation in Unreal to know where to check for evidence of any of those potential causes. Do you observe a similar problem with specular light, or only diffuse? That could help us identify if the normals are stuck.